# IP Whitelist Firebase Cloud Functions in MongoDB Cluster

Tags: javascript, mongodb, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

How do I add my Firebase Cloud Functions to my MongoDB cluster's IP whitelist?

Error Message:
[image: Error Message]

Comment: In general, it is best to paste the error message into the question rather than attach a screenshot.

Comment: Did you get it working? I'm facing the same issue. I thought I could use VPC but no support for that either, https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/552

Answer (score -2):

This worked for me.

Add `0.0.0.0/0` to your whitelist.

This will allow all ip addresses.

Comment: this will make ur mongo-db venerable to attacks.